# Using an overflow operator in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift, and I am reading The Big Nerd Ranch Guide. I came across this example:

He wants me to get the value of z

```
let y: Int8 = 120 
let z = y &+ 10 
print ("120 &+ 10 is \(z)")
```

He mentioned that the result of overflow-adding 120 + 10 and storing the result into an Int8 is -126

I don't understand the logic of this result. I tried to read more resources about the overflow operators, but I got more confused. I'd greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Did you have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID37 in the Swift reference? It is documented and nicely demonstrated with examples.

Comment: @MartinR  No, I didn't. I will have a look at this now. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Thank you very much. I've read it before but I didn't fully understand the logic yet.

Comment: Int8 can have values from -128 to 128. By adding the bit value of 10 to 120, when the operation is completed it overflows to negative. -128 + 2 = -126

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ `-128...127` Including zero (1 byte - 8-bit = 2^8  = 256)

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ Got it. Many thanks :)

Comment: @LeoDabus up to* shoot 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In binary, the value of y, 120 is:

01111000

If you add 10 to that (which is 1010 in binary) you get:

10000010

If you take that binary pattern and interpret it as a signed 8 bit integer, you note that the high bit is 1 (which means the number is negative) and the value of the negative number is the twos complement of the pattern (0000010) which is (1111101 + 1) or (1111110) which is 126

Therefore the result is -126

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification.